# Get webpage source if website using strict transport security

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the source or webpage and want to fill in multyline textbox using c#. My code is given below..

```
void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Error == null) && !e.Cancelled)
    {
        string content = e.Result;
        valuetxt.Text = content.ToString();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string address = "https://www.justdial.com";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=
            new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
    }
```

This code is working fine for maximum website but for some websites this return "403 forbidden" error and unable to return source code eg. justdial.com, codeplex.com etc. But in the browser webpage working normally.
Can anyone help me to know why this code unable to get source of webpage. Thanks in advance, Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You need to add `header` (`cookie`) with proper credentials for the page.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks. I updated my code with these 3 lines of code and i got properly working. 'request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;'